# What exactly does MemoryInUse measure?

Tags: performance-tuning, memory

I have a long-running process, which takes about half a day to complete. The main "loop" is a `Fold` of (roughly) the following structure:

```
ClearAll[f, res];
f[x1_, x2_] := (
    Print[MemoryInUse[]];
    (* Do something with x1 and x2. *)
);
res = Fold[f, startingVal, Range[1000]];
```

Now, this always returns, even though, predictably and understandably, it takes a long time to complete. In the course of the run, I see messages like:

```
140.01 MB
146.33 MB
158.79 MB
...
```

The printed number always keeps going up, as if the programme were leaking memory. However, the memory usage indicated by Task Manager (Windows 10 Pro 64-bit) remains quite steady. There has never been a crash because of the memory usage, even after 12-hour-long runs. But the number keeps ticking upwards monotonically.

So, what is `MemoryInUse` measuring? And is the measurement related to anything useful?